# Subtracting values in 2 different list in android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a integer array of years and its corresponding values it looks like the below code

```
int[] earningYear = {2012,2013,2014};
int[] earningAmount = {100,150,120};
int[] expenseYear = {2012,2014};
int[] expenseAmount = {50,30};
```

i want to subtract expenseAmount from earningsAmount corresponding to year and the output list should look like this

```
int[] savingsYear = {2012,2013,2014};
int[] savingsamount = {50,150,90};
```

please help me in doing this. Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be too tricky when using arrays (don't know which language you are working with) try to use some Collection  classes (like Map<T,T> in java or Dictionary<T,T> in c#.Net) that has 1-1 mapping of elements. Things would be too simple then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers given by @umair.ali and @Casper are good, converting your arrays to Maps is the way to go.
I would suggest using `TreeMap` (or other implementation of `SortMap` interface). TreeMap sorts its keys in ascending order by default. That way, if you **really** want to have plain array of savings as result, you won't have to do any awkward map sorting after processing.

Here's complete example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SavingsApp {

    public Map<Integer, Integer> arraysToMap(int[] years, int[] money) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        if (years == null || money == null || years.length != money.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        for (int i=0; i< years.length; i++ ) {
            newMap.put(years[i], money[i]);
        }

        return newMap;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> calculateSavings(Map<Integer, Integer> earningsMap, Map<Integer, Integer>expensesMap) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> savingsMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        savingsMap.putAll(earningsMap);

        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> expensePerYear : expensesMap.entrySet()) {
            Integer year = expensePerYear.getKey();
            Integer expense = expensePerYear.getValue();

            Integer earning = savingsMap.get(year);
            if (earning == null) {
                earning = 0;
            }
            savingsMap.put(year, earning-expense);
        }
        return savingsMap;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] earningYear = {2012,2013,2014};
        int[] earningAmount = {100,150,120};
        int[] expenseYear = {2012,2014};
        int[] expenseAmount = {50,30};

        SavingsApp app = new SavingsApp();

        // convert arrays to maps
        Map<Integer, Integer> earningsMap = app.arraysToMap(earningYear, earningAmount);
        Map<Integer, Integer> expensesMap = app.arraysToMap(expenseYear, expenseAmount);

        // compute savings per year
        Map<Integer, Integer> savingsMap = app.calculateSavings(earningsMap, expensesMap);

        // convert result map to array
        List<Integer> savingsList = new ArrayList<Integer>(savingsMap.values());
        Integer[] savingsArray = new Integer[savingsList.size()];
        savingsList.toArray(savingsArray);
    }
}
```

One thing to notice is that `savingsArray` will be of `Integer[]` type instead of `int[]`.

Comment: That is a good solution for pure Java, but for Android it's advisable to avoid creating new objects, if possible. This code above will create a number of `Entry` objects in the map, boxed `Integer` primitives, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If earningYear always contains all years and both earningYear and expenseYear are sorted, then this would be a possible solution

```
int[] earningYear = {2012,2013,2014};
int[] earningAmount = {100,150,120};
int[] expenseYear = {2012,2014};
int[] expenseAmount = {50,30};

int[] savingsYear = new int[earningYear.length()];
int[] savingsAmount = new int[earningYear.length()];

int expenseYearIndex = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < earningYear.length(); i++) {
    savingsYear[i] = earningYear[i];
    savingsAmount[i] = earningsAmount[i];
    if(expenseYear.length() > 0 && expenseYear[expenseYearIndex] == earningYear[i]) {
        savingsAmount[i] -= expenseYear[expenseYearIndex];
        expenseYearIndex++;
    }
}
```

This should do it.

However a better solution would be something with a List, already suggested, and some objects holding the year and the amount for the year.

Comment: thank u for the answer. as i am new to android can u pls tel me how use lists to do this stuff, thank u

Comment: @Paweł Wyrwiński gives a answer for that. A little advice would be to learn a little Java, since this can be translated to a Java specific problem more than a Android one.